# using the Internationalization API results in much longer load times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I recently switched to using the Internationalization API in one of my React apps.

Here is the function that uses it:

```
const randomDate = (start, end) => {
  var date = new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()))
  var formattedDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date);
  return formattedDate;
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
postDate: randomDate(new Date(2019, 9, 1), new Date())
```

I generated 100,000 rows of random data and 'postDate' is in each row.

So I do realize I'm using it a lot.

However, if I replace it with this:

```
const randomDate = (start, end) => {
  var date = new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()))
  return date;
}
```

It's runs noticeably faster.

Is there a way to optimize my code to make it run faster while still using the Internationalization API?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you always using the same start/end dates for all 100k rows?

Comment: @larz yes, every row has this range passed to it: new Date(2019, 9, 1), new Date()

Comment: You can reuse the Date object from `new Date(2019, 9, 1)` rather than creating a new one over and over again.   In `randomDate()`, you can call `start.getTime()` once and use that result both places you need it rather than call it twice. Or, you can look and test for a faster implementation of `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date);`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Hi, I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'look and test for a faster implementation of new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date); thanks

Comment: @jfriend00 In regards to reusing objects, you mean instead of passing the same arguments over and over, just set both dates as global variables?

Comment: There are alternate implementations of the `Intl.DateTimeFormat()` function you could test out.  Well, the `new Date(2019, 9, 1)` doesn't have to be a global, but you can create it once, save it in a variable somewhere appropriate and reuse the same object over and over.  Anytime you're doing something 100k times, you'd like to avoid repeating something.  For that matter, it looks like you could save `new Date(2019, 9, 1).getTime()` and just pass that in.

Comment: @jfriend00 I found the Intl spec here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat  There are different ones?

Comment: Same spec.  Different implementations: Have a [look](https://www.google.com/search?q=Intl.DateTimeFormat+npm).